# how do I make a specific page SSL secured with a specific subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I have my website and the page that I accept credit cards I want to have SSL. I got my SSL all setup for the subdomain: secure.website.com

So, how do I make sure that the page I accept credit cards on always is https and has a subdomain of secure.website.com.

The address is: http://www.website.com/subscriptions/new

and that needs to be

https://secure.website.com/subscriptions/new

how do I make it always render that URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the protocol and the subdomain parameters to url_for. You will need to include the url_for modifications as described here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

The end result would be:

```
<%= url_for(:action => 'new', :controller => 'subscriptions', :only_path => false, :protocol => 'https', :subdomain => 'secure') %>
```